# NoSuchAlgorithmException in SSLContext.getInstance

Tags: java, ssl

I am getting `NoSuchAlgorithmException` in the following code:

```
 @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
 @PrepareForTest({CloudWatchHelper.class})
 class MyTest {
 ....
 final SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
 ...
 }
```

Stack trace:

```
[junit] class configured for SSLContext: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$TLSContext not a SSLContext
[junit] java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: class configured for SSLContext: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$TLSContext not a SSLContext
[junit]     at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.checkSuperClass(GetInstance.java:260)
[junit]     at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:237)
[junit]     at sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:164)
[junit]     at javax.net.ssl.SSLContext.getInstance(SSLContext.java:156)
```

I want to know what is the reason behind `NoSuchAlgorithmException`.

Comment: You've messed up your security.providers file.

Comment: What JRE are you using? What does -Djavax.net.debug=all provide?

Comment: @siom Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_144-b01)

Answer (score -5, accepted):

I realized that I got exception because of:

```
 @RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
 @PrepareForTest({CloudWatchHelper.class})
```

Comment: What was your actual resolution to the issue?

Comment: Actually, I found a resolution via this [post](http://mathieuhicauber-java.blogspot.co.uk/2013/07/powermock-and-ssl-context.html).  The bottom line is that you need to add:  `@PowerMockIgnore({ "javax.net.ssl.*", "javax.security.*" })`.

Answer (score 14):

Adding the following annotation to my test class fixed this issue for me:

```
@PowerMockIgnore({ "javax.net.ssl.*", "javax.security.*" })
```

Comment: Worth noting this is mentioned in a comment below, but having this as an answer is probably a more generally useful fix than the accepted answer which is something specific to `CloudWatchHelper`, but this error can occur from many different classes using PowerMock.